# Unsolved Ring Puzzle

Tags: mechanical-puzzles

I have not been able to solve this puzzle. I believe that the objective is to remove the larger circular ring, not the 2 smaller ones.

[image: photo of puzzle]

Comment: Looks a lot like a glorified version of the horseshoe puzzle. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmFzByxFg-A

Comment: Great video. I agree that the puzzle is topologically equivalent (homeomorphic) to the horseshoe puzzle. I don't know if that means I can apply the same solution method. I yanked the ring off the puzzle out of impatience and gave up. Right now, I have to study, so I'll just declare the puzzle solved by homeomorphism and come back to it later.

Comment: I don't think those are the same. The big weird shape is a closed loop, not an open horseshoe. If one of those horseshoes were closed, that method wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Horseshoe and Ring puzzle, personalized for someone with initials S.I.G..

I found this [visual solution](https://www.instructables.com/id/Solving-the-Horseshoe-and-Ring-Puzzle/) for it, which I think explains the solution clearer than a video.

First notice that the ring is not actually linked into the horseshoes - so it is on the outside, and so we are trying to transform the horseshoes into a shape that makes this relation more obvious.

If you look at step 4. the trick to see if that the ring can be removed over horseshoe 34 due to the slack in the chain between ends 1 and 3 (move the part of the ring closest to the camera at 4 along the ring to 3).

Now you can use the same trick to remove the ring from your puzzle.

Comment: The explanation for the lettering is that the puzzles were given out by the trading firm Susquehanna International Group. Regardless, nice answer.